# Exclude child folders from Live Mesh

Tags: windows-live, windows-live-mesh

Easy as the title says it... I want to sync up some folders and exclude child's of that or file extensions...

Has anybody figured that out yet?

Edit: I'm talking about [Windows Live Mesh 2011](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh?os=other)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to exlude child folders from syncing, just add the system attribute to it.  Windows Live Mesh will [not sync system files](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh-sync-file-types-ui). You can also do this with individual files.

Open a CMD prompt and type:

```
attrib +s c:\mysyncedfolder\myexcludedfolder
```

Comment: I was talking about Live Mesh 2011, I'll edit my question, thanks for your feedback

Comment: Does this work and is there any supporting documentation from Microsoft or is this just an unknown quirk?

Comment: @mindless.panda: Live Mesh will not sync system files, which is pretty sensible. See here: http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh-sync-file-types-ui

Comment: @paradroid Awesome, thanks. Wish they made it configurable.