# Windows Live Mesh - Selectively not sync a specific subdirectory

Tags: windows, macos, windows-live-mesh

I'd like to sync the my iTunes directory on my Mac (osx lion) over to my PC (windows server 2008); however, I'd like to prevent it from syncing the podcast directory as this is not important to me for syncing, but represents a large amount of data. Unfortunately I cannot specify where iTunes places this specific directory.

Is there a way to specifically prevent Mesh from syncing a specific sub directory of one of it's synced folders? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows side, this question is identical to [Exclude child folders from Live Mesh](https://superuser.com/q/199119/54568). Not sure about OS X.